# Inconsistent pairs or groups of words in the old (1995) orthography

Tags: spelling, history

As I had already graduated in 1996, I suffer very much from new orthography, of which there have been various after-reforms. I thought it would help to put everything into perspective, if we educated ourselves on the shortcomings of the old orthography. For this to become a very well defined question, I will ONLY ask about inconsistent pairs of words in the old orthography, no rules such as ß!

Example:
Nummer und nummern (Verb) **aber** Numerus/numerieren/Numerik/numerisch

Comment: Why is this a bad question? I myself very much prefer the old orthography. But every orthography has pathological cases! Why not learn about them? Many people still argue about the reform.

Comment: Ich habe noch nicht ganz verstanden, worin die Inkonsistenz bestanden haben soll. Das Wort _Nummer_ wird doch auch nach neuer Rechtschreibung noch mit zwei _n_ geschrieben – wegen des kurzen _u_ berechtigterweise –, wiewohl das aus dem Lateinischen stammende _Numerus_ nur ein _n_ hat. Auch die Änderung von _numerieren_ zu _nummerieren_ hat nichts mit Konsistenz zu tun, sondern damit, dass man das Verb heute eher mit _Nummer_ assoziiert.

Comment: @ die Inkonsistenz wurde ja auch nicht behoben! Sie besteht eben darin, daß man in der Schreibung der Ableitungen von Numerus nicht konsistent ist. Ganz unabhängig davon, ob das wünschenswert ist, wäre es doch interessant solche Fälle zu kennen, denn „nummerieren“ war zum Beispiel ein sehr beliebter Rechtschreibfehler, der jetzt richtig ist

Comment: Dann verstehe ich die Frage wohl wirklich nicht. Ich dachte, der OP wolle verstehen, welche Inkonsistenzen es bei bestimmten Wortpaaren mit der alten Rechtschreibung gab, die dazu geführt hätten, dass eben diese Inkonsistenzen durch die neue Rechtschreibung aufgehoben wurden.

Comment: If I got it right, your question is: Which words that can be grouped by semantics differed in spelling according to the old orthography? Wouldn't that be asking for a list (, which is frowned upon in this community)?

Comment: @Marzipanherz indeed. I was not aware of the fact that  lists were discouraged. There are many highly voted questions resulting in lists, such as words with different genders!

Comment: @Ludi Oh well, I might mix it up with an other SE community. Maybe check the "which questions to ask/avoid" section of the help to make sure :)

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich eigentlich wollte ich erstmal die Schwächen erkennen, egal ob sie behoben wurden oder nicht, den das hilft mir, mich zu distanzieren. Aber behobene Inkonsistenzen zählen natürlich auch. Vielleicht müssen wir es auf sie einengen, damit es nicht opinion based wird? Aber ich würde es erstmal so versuchen.

Comment: @Ludi Ach das war deine eigene Frage? Das sehe ich hier nicht, bei mir steht _Community Wiki_.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Ja. Ich habe sie der Community vermacht, in der Hoffnung, daß eine ausgeglichene Diskussion entsteht, denn ich war und bin nicht so für die Reform :)

Comment: Also mir fallen da eher Dinge wie _Schänke_ versus _Schenke_ und ähnliche Umlaut-Inkonsistenzen ein.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich von mir aus alles willkommen

Comment: Möchtest du nur Beispiele für inkonsistente Schreibung des gemeinsamen Wortstammes oder auch andere systematische Schwächen? Letzteres wäre bspw. _Auto fahren_ vs. _radfahren_. Einiges ist auch Volksetymologie, so _einbleuen/einbläuen_ oder _Stengel/Stängel_. Angeben gibt es unterschiedliche theoretische Herangehensweisen, z. B. bei _Tip/Tipp_.

Comment: @Crissov erstmal nur ersteres, damit es übersichtlich bleibt. Aber wenn es sich gut definieren läßt, können wir ja für andere Typen eine weitere Frage eröffnen.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of pairs in traditional and reform spelling:

> plazieren - platzieren

Das gute alte "plazieren" kam aus dem Französischen (*placer*); "platzieren" wurde eingeführt, weil man glaubte, dass die Kinderlein, die das Schreiben lernen sollen, sich leichter damit tun, weil es auch "Platz" heißt.

Comment: Es ging eigentlich nicht um den Vergleich alt/neu, sondern um die „Inkonsistenz“ Platz/plazieren. Es ist aber ein guter Beitrag.